# Total minutes in a duration in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, duration

I recently wanted to know the difference in minutes and/or hours in a `duration.between` in `neo4j`.

```
MATCH (yv:YoutubeVideo)
WHERE datetime(yv.publishedAt) >= datetime('2021-11-16T12:05:47.897962')
WITH yv, duration.between(datetime('2021-11-16T12:05:47.897962'), yv.publishedAt).minutes as minutes,
yv.publishedAt as expectedDate,
datetime('2021-11-16T12:05:47.897962') as startDate
RETURN duration.between(datetime('2021-11-16T12:05:47.897962'), yv.publishedAt) as duration, startDate,
expectedDate + duration({minutes:minutes}) as expectedRes,
startDate + duration({minutes:minutes})as  resultDate
LIMIT 1
```

This gives result:
[image]

This seems to be okay, but it isn't.
As you can see I want to add the minutes of the `duration` to `startDate` to get the `expectedRes`. I realized that the `duration.between(datetime('2021-11-16T12:05:47.897962'), yv.publishedAt).minutes` returns only the minutes in the hour, not including the days. Which results in `resultDate`.

A better example:
Say the `duration` is 3 days, 4 hours en 20 minutes. If I do `.minutes`, I'll receive 260 minutes as result (This is the result of hours * minutes in an hour + leftover minutes, in this case 4 * 60 + 20), but I want the result to be 4580 (This is the result of (days * hours + leftover hours) * minutes in an hour + leftover minutes, in this case (3 * 24 + 4) * 60 + 20 )

Is there a way to get the total minutes of the `duration` (including the days) without doing that equation in my `Cypher` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [apoc temporal](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/temporal/temporal-conversions/) or [apoc dates](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.date/apoc.date.add/).

Comment: Gives me the same result as I stated before.

Comment: Looks like you need to do the calculation in your cypher query. The other option is to write your own user defined function. I'd go with the equation in the cypher query.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, it seemed to be the only way.

Comment: Sometimes the first solution is best!!!